# Redirect request to another route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an `Asp.net Web Api` method called `Publish` which acts either as `Create` or as `Update`, based on what parameters it receives.

Is possible, to redirect the request to another api method? (with all the request data and request headers - so the model binding works automatically)

Note: I don't want to return an `HttpStatusCode.Moved` response. I just want to redirect the action - internally.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1.0/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("publish")]
    public void Publish()
    {
        // this is the entry point

        if (Request.Headers.Contains("X-Product-Code"))
        {
            // redirect request to Update
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect request to Create
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    public void Create(CreateViewModel viewModel)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("update")]
    public void Update(UpdateViewModel viewModel)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you need to do here is not redirect but abstract the logic from your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just write you logic here:

```
 if (Request.Headers.Contains("X-Product-Code"))
        {
            // redirect request to Update
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect request to Create
        }
```

like:

```
 if (Request.Headers.Contains("X-Product-Code"))
        {
            // 1) Create UpdateViewModel model = new UpdateViewModel(); 
            // set data
            // 2) Call Create(model)
        }
        else
        {
            // 1) Create CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel (); 
            // set data
            // 2) Call Update(model)
        }
```

Comment: `// 1) Create UpdateViewModel model = new UpdateViewModel();`
Exactly this is what i am trying to avoid - manually creating the View Models

Comment: Reading the request parameters and mapping them to the actually View Model properties - like key/pair values.

Comment: When you do it manually - you can be sure that your model is valid. I don't say that you need do it in all your code, but here I think it be nice

Comment: Its not the answer i was looking for but i think i'll have to do it like this in the end

Answer (score 0):

Controller actions and model binding are for mapping HTTP requests to code entry points - if you need to call one controller action from another, you are doing something wrong.

In this scenario it is probably better to use a unified view model and abstract your logic to a service.

In the example below, I have moved whatever code is in those methods to a separate class (ProductsService) so that it can easily be called from both controller actions. If you need to do model validation, setting of cookies or other stuff, you can do this in a private method inside the controller, which, again, you can call from both actions:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ProductsService _service = new ProductsService();

    public void Publish(CreateOrUpdateViewModel model)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.Contains("X-Product-Code"))
        {
            _service.Create(Mapper.MapProduct(model));
        }
        else
        {
            _service.Update(Mapper.MapProduct(model));
        }
    }

    public void Update(CreateOrUpdateViewModel model)
    {
        _service.Update(Mapper.MapProduct(model));
    }

    // etc.
}
```